# Programmatically update the code of a CodeModule. Issue with character "_" in original copied code

Tags: excel, vba

I am updating the code of a module copying it from another module. I replace the whole code.
Actually, the code is in a sheet (both original and destination), not in a module.

The piece of code that copies it is:

```
Dim codeModDestination As CodeModule
Dim codeModOriginal As CodeModule
                
'..... Set CodeModules, etc.
                
'Delete the existing code at the destination CodeModule    
codeModDestination.DeleteLines 1, codeModDestination.CountOfLines 

Dim fila As Long
For fila = 1 To codeModOriginal.CountOfLines
    codeModDestination.InsertLines codeModDestination.CountOfLines + 1, _
                                   codeModOriginal.Lines(fila, 1)
Next fila
```

It copies the whole code of the original module, but the lines split with the character "_" get a blank line between them, making a code that launches a compile error:

Original code:

```
    Msgbox "Hello" + vbLf + _
        "World"
```

Is transformed into:

```
    Msgbox "Hello" + vbLf + _

        "World"
```

All other code is copied correctly, but I can't get into Interruption mode, so I don't know what is going on.

EDIT:

I found a workaround, but I am not sure why it works:

```
Dim fila, insert_before As Long
insert_before = 0
For fila = 1 To codeModOriginal.CountOfLines
    codeModDestination.InsertLines codeModDestination.CountOfLines + 1 - insert_before, _
                                   codeModOriginal.Lines(fila, 1)
    insert_before = 0
    If fila <> codeMod.CountOfLines Then
        debug.print fila
        insert_before = 1
    End If

Next fila
```

`insert_before` is 0 for the first 20 lines, until the first instruction with "_" is found. Then it is always 1.

Comment: You say "I replace the whole code.". If you do this, why don't you delete this module and import the module that you want to copy from?

Comment: It is not a module, but a spreadsheet with data, I can't delete it. What we are doing is copying spreadsheets with old code (but useful data) and then updating the code with that function.

Comment: The spreadsheet code that we are updating is a `Worksheet_Change` sub that can't be placed elsewhere

Comment: In the sheet module, you only want to replace the  ``Worksheet_Change`` with the ``Worksheet_Change`` code in another module, or you delete all the sheet module code and paste the new ``Worksheet_Change`` from the other module?

Comment: @Eliofernandes We change the `Worksheet_Change` sub but also some constant declaration, so it is better to replace the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the code to delete the module content.

My solution for you is to get the code from the module you want and insert it in the  destination module using **InsertLines** instead of using a loop.

The Main procedure, shows an example how to copy all the code from sheet1 to sheet2.

```
Option Explicit

Public code As String

Private Sub Main()
    ' Find procedure
    code = Module_GetAllContent("Sheet1")
    Debug.Print code
    
    ' Add procedure to code module
    If code <> vbNullString Then Call Module_AddCode("Sheet2")
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Get all module content
'----------------------------------------------------------
Function Module_GetAllContent(ByVal codName As String) As String
    On Error GoTo errProject
        With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(codName).CodeModule
            code = .Lines(1, .CountOfLines)
        End With
    
    ' Return
    Module_GetAllContent = code

exitRoutine:
    ' Exit
    Exit Function

errProject:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume exitRoutine
End Function

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Add code to module
'----------------------------------------------------------
Sub Module_AddCode(ByVal codName As String)
    On Error GoTo errProject
        With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(codName).CodeModule
            .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, code
        End With
        
exitRoutine:
    Exit Sub

errProject:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume exitRoutine
End Sub
```