# Copying Macros to new workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, file

Please help, I can run a macro to create multiple new workbooks from a drop down list and save to a specified location . In the original file there are  Macros that find specific files and worksheets to place in the file. Is there a way to copy over the Macros to all the new worksheets? I have tried using macros form a personal workbook but they don't seem to work. Thanks

Comment: You can export modules as .bas files, and macros embedded in work sheets can be exported as .cls files.

Comment: Hi For the bas files you have to open the VB window and import which would be quite time consuming,  is there a quicker way? I have tried assigning saved macros to the 'Buttons' in the saved workbooks but they don't seem to work as in it won't find the folders and worksheets, thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Why don't you describe a real scenario in more detail? For example, *I want to copy this workbook's worksheets that contain codes to a new workbook. I also want to copy the modules of this workbook...*

Comment: Hi, I trying to find an efficient way to copy the macro codes to all of the new workbooks, could I perhaps save the new workbooks as macro enabled books ?

Comment: Macros can be in several locations: in the `ThisWorkbook` module, in a sheet module e.g. `Sheet1`, in a standard module e.g. `Module1` and in a class module e.g. `Class1`. Which one(s) do you want to copy where to? When you have macros in an unsaved workbook, they will work already. If you want to keep them after saving, you need to save the 
 new workbook by using either the `.xlsm` or the `.xlsb` extension.

Comment: Take a look at the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69085979/programmatically-update-the-code-of-a-codemodule-issue-with-character-in-or) I think it's a starting point! Try do adapt to your needs.

Comment: You will run into issues with security by attempting to alter the macros in a second book from a first (which is basically what a virus can/would potentially do). Your OS makes it difficult to do this so if you actually wanted to do this (which I don't recommend) you would need to alter some trust centre permissions. Perhaps look at template files instead? (.xlst)

Answer (score 1):

### Open a Copy (Template) of ThisWorkbook

- This will create a copy (`SaveCopyAs`) of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`) in an existing folder (`FolderPath`). Then it will open the copy (`OldFilePath`) and save it as a template (`NewFilePath`) and close it. Then it will delete the copy and open the template (`LeftBaseName & "Template1"`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OpenMyTemplate()
    Const ProcName As String = "OpenMyTemplate"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test" ' adjust this (has to exist)
    Const RightBaseName As String = "Template"
    Const NewExtension As String = ".xltm"
    
    Dim wbName As String: wbName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    
    Dim DotPosition As Long: DotPosition = InStrRev(wbName, ".")
    Dim LeftBaseName As String: LeftBaseName = Left(wbName, DotPosition - 1)
    
    Dim OldExtension As String
    OldExtension = Right(wbName, Len(wbName) - DotPosition)
    
    Dim BaseName As String: BaseName = LeftBaseName & RightBaseName
    
    Dim BaseNamePath As String
    BaseNamePath = FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & BaseName
    
    Dim OldFilePath As String: OldFilePath = BaseNamePath & OldExtension
    ' Save a copy of the workbook containing this code
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs OldFilePath
    
    Dim NewFilePath As String: NewFilePath = BaseNamePath & NewExtension
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With Workbooks.Open(OldFilePath) ' open the copy
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        .SaveAs NewFilePath, xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled ' save as template
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    
    Kill OldFilePath ' delete the copy
    
    Workbooks.Open NewFilePath ' open the template

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```